# How to collect the indices of an array X that has the same lengths between elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to make an array Z that  have indexes of the most frequent occurring difference between two elements in the array X. So if the most frequent occurring difference between two elements in X is 3 then I would get all the indexes in X that have that difference into array Z.

```
x = [ 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.6];
ct = 0;
difference_x = diff(x);
unique_x = unique(difference_x);
for i = 1:length(unique_x)
    for j = 1:length(x)
           space_between_elements = abs(x(i)-x(i+1));
           if space_between_elements  == difference_x
                ct = ct + 1;
                space_set(i,ct) = j;
           end
     end
end
```

I Don´t get the indexes of X containing the most frequent difference from this code.

Comment: Please also type out the solution that you want - your description is unclear. Does the nested loop you posted post the correct answer? Either way what is your problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to find **how many unique differences there are**, with "difference" interpreted **in an absoulte-value sense**; and also find **how many times each difference occurs**.

You can do that as follows:

```
x = [ 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.6]; %// data
difference_x = abs(diff(x));
unique_x = unique(difference_x); %// all differences
counts = histc(difference_x, unique_x); %// count for each difference
```

However, comparing reals for uniqueness (or equality) is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) because of finite precision. You should rather apply a **tolerance** to declare two values as "equal":

```
x = [ 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.6]; %// data
tol = 1e-6; %// tolerance
difference_x = abs(diff(x));
difference_x = round(difference_x/tol)*tol; %// apply tolerance
unique_x = unique(difference_x); %// all differences
counts = histc(difference_x, unique_x); %// count for each difference
```

With your example `x`, the second approach gives

```
>> unique_x
unique_x =
         0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000
>> counts
counts =
     1     4     3     2
```

Comment: How would I collect the indices of the array X using the highest unique_x counts. Something like
index = find(counts==max(counts));
if unique_x(index)==difference_X
    % collects the index number in X
end